# Calendar to learn Linux?

Tags: learning

I've been sifting through websites and forums trying to locate a way to schedule learning in a calendar type of way and have had little success. Is there a calendar or schedule that would do something like:

April 12 (or day 1) - learn HAL, /proc and udev

April 13 (or day 2) learn - lsusb, lspci

so that I could keep an organized and driven approach to learning Linux?

EDIT: does there exist a calendarized curriculum for LPIC/Linux+ learning?

Comment: If you want a program of learning, install a rolling release distro. Also, HAL is deprecated, so you can cross that off your list...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for learning materials. Voting to close as per http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/2642/

Comment: Thanks for replies! I read the meta and will not post questions of this nature again. Totally reasonable and i could see where the broadness could being a wellspring of answers to keep me spinning in circles and not obtain my goal.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are aiming towards the system side of Linux. 
and as far as i can say your approach is decent too... but a bit ambitious.

The key to master Linux is not to take it down in one go... start with the basics, target one subsystem or area, and master it. once you are comfortable in that zone it will be easier to master others.

Still a lots of hands on is needed and that can be done any way you like.

Comment: Thank you! I've become comfortable with a handful of distros and have decided to step it up and learn LPIC/Linux+ material. I believe a more accurate question would be: does there exist a calendarized curriculum for LPIC/Linux+ learning?

Comment: you can always follow the LinuxFoundation newsletters to know of the current courses being offered. try edX, OCW among others, best of all would be to go "hackermode". make some 'informed' changes and observe the results. it will be great if you have a sacrificial system to tinker with, i use my RaspberryPi for the same.

Answer (score 0):

As each day passes improvements are implemented and old code is sloughed off - the linux kernel is an evolving thing. You cannot necessarily "calendarize" it because the calendar would very soon be out-of-date. That said, you can do [linux from scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) which is an ever-evolving thing as well.